# When click element it appear elsewhere javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a JavaScript / jQuery code that will allow me when I click one of the elements "A" or "B" to appear in a place (span tags).

It's basically a selection and a display of that selection, when i click element "B", in the span tag should appear "B", if click on "A" then element "A" will appear in the span tag.

```html
    
<!-- Where should be displayed elements A or B -->
 <span>...</span>


<!-- The elements to click on -->
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
```

Comment: Please provide the javascript you have tried

Comment: i haven t try any, i do not know how to start, i am javascript rookie

Comment: Research onclick events: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
getElementById: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp
and InnerHMTL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use click event and text.

```js
$('h1').click((e) => { $('span').text($(e.target).text());})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>...</span>
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with pure Javascript could be:

```
    const headings = document.querySelectorAll('.heading');
    const result = document.querySelector('#result');

    headings.forEach(heading => {
        heading.addEventListener('click', () => {
            result.innerText = heading.innerText;
        });
    });
```

It's good to identify the elements on the page somehow, here I placed an id = "result" on the span element, and class = "heading" to both headings A and B (you could also select those elements with document.getElementsByTagName when you haven't got any better identifiers like classes and IDs). I grabbed the elements from the DOM and stored them in variables. Then you just loop through the headings and add click event listeners to them, on the click you take the innerText from the clicked heading and place it as innerText into the span.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Where should be displayed elements A or B -->
<span>...</span>


<!-- The elements to click on -->
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>

<script>

/**
 * Quick solution without changing the html markup
 * could be something like this. But it could be
 * improved with better markup thus there could be
 * better structured script. It's pure JS.
 */

// Select the element where the value of selection 
// should be outputed.
const output = document.querySelector('span');

// Select all elements that are considered an option.
const variant = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

// Elements are in array, so you need to loop through 
// them. For loop performs better than forEach.
// We need some counter, we name it i, but you can
// name it anything you want. Arrays are 0 indexed,
// so we assign the initial value 0. Next we need
// a condition, how long should the loop run. 
// So as long it’s less than count of variants, 
// perform the actions. Last in the for loop is
// what should happen after sequention, we increment 
// our counter i by one, alternative of i++ could be
// i += 1.
for (let i = 0; i < variant.length; i++) {
    // We take variant[i] - starting from 0 to 1 and then
    // we add event listener, that listens for clicks.
    // After variant is clicked, we pass an anonymous
    // function.
    variant[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        // This function simply takes the inner text
        // of variant and makes it inner text of
        // the output.
        output.innerText = variant[i].innerText;
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```